# a practical problem about R for loop and if statement

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

first, I got 2 feature which are character initially.

```
train_address = train$address
test_address = test$address
```

and then I bind them together.

```
address = c(train_address, test_address)
```

and then I change it from character to integer because I will dummy them later and I want to process it faster.(those character are not in English)

```
train_address = as.integer(factor(train_address, levels = unique(address)))
test_address = as.integer(factor(test_address, levels = unique(address)))
```

and now, here is the problem. code is shown below.

My goal is to transfer all the data which in train but not in test to 0.

```
for (a in train_address) {
  if (!(train_address[a] %in% test_address)) {
    train_address[a] = 0
  }
}

train_address = as.factor(train_address)
test_address = as.factor(test_address)
```

after I process the data in this way, it should be:

> the number of factor of test + 1 = the number of factor of train

(because R start from 1 so 0 is not been used until I transfer some of the data in train via the for loop  above)

but in reality, difference between the number of factor of train and of test is 400+.

I know there must be something wrong about the code but I don't know where...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should do the trick.

You don't need loop for this but use vectorized manipulation.

```
train_address[!(train_address %in test_address)] <- 0
```

Explanation :

`(train_address %in test_address)` gives boolean vector where `TRUE` means to element in `train_address` is in `test_address`

`!` negates that boolean vector

`train_address[!(train_address %in test_address)]` gives all the elements in train_address that are not in test_address.

finally you set them to zero by our command `train_address[!(train_address %in test_address)] <- 0`